Linear space and vector space correlation
I'm confused with definition of vector space and field.
According to wiki vector_space and field.
Vector space over some field is defined as set of element in $V$ and binary operations that satisfies:

$+:V+V\rightarrow V$
$*:F+V\rightarrow V$

So multiplication of elements in $V$ defined for with relation to elements in field $F$.
But I'm reading fascinating Solomon book. Numerical Algorithms. And I got stuck with his contary example of non linear operation.
It states:
$g(x,y)=xy^2$ is not linear. Because $g(1, 1)=1$, but $g(2, 2) \neq 2g(1, 1)$.
As I understand linear function defined for elements of some vector space, so $x,y$ are vectors. But example above multiplies vectors, despite this operations ain't defined for vector space elements.

Why does this example works?

Because multiplication is defined when vector $\in R$?

If so it won't expand to $R^n, n > 1$?



That function $g$ is a function from the real vector space $\Bbb R^2$ into the real vector space $\Bbb R$. The expression $xy^2$ makes no sense for vectors in general, but here $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, and so, yes, it makes sense. Besides, the vector here is neither $x$ nor $y$; it's the pair $(x,y)$.
As another example, suppose that you are working with the vector space $\Bbb R[x]$ of all polynomial functions from $\Bbb R$ into itself. If $P\in\Bbb R[x]$, it makes sens to talk about $P'$ (and $P\mapsto P'$ turns out to be a linear map), although in general there is no such thing as the derivative of a vector.

Yep, kind messed up with R, of course vector here is R^2. Thanks for emphasizing it.
Thanks for the answer

I'm glad I could help.
